# Can a where cause on an IQueryable ever cause another element to be returned, rather than not using it?

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

I have a cms system (sitecore) where there is a piece of code that gets some items from an index via an IQueryable.

Sometimes the query is filtered, sometimes it is not.

The code I have looks like this:

```
        if (isFiltered)
        {
            searchResults = query.Where(predicate).GetResults();
        } else
        {
            searchResults = query.GetResults();

        }


        // {6C97F09B-D304-4182-92D0-CB0A29B21AE3}
        var ss = searchResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Document.ItemId.ToString() == "{6C97F09B-D304-4182-92D0-CB0A29B21AE3}");
```

Now, the strange thing that happens, is that when isfiltered is true, then `ss` is present, but when it is not filtered then `ss` is null.

This confuses me, since the way I understand it, when you use `where` then the resulting list should also be a subset of what would be returned if it were not used.

So my question is, can a query where a `where` clause is used ever return elements that would not be returned if you do not use it?

Comment: What is `GetResults`?

Comment: Sorry, it is an sitecore extension for IQueryable, and is described as `Gets the results.`

Comment: Pagination somewhere? If you get 100 records back, with the filter the wanted id is in the returned set. Without the filter it would show up in a subsequent page.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, the `searchresults` return 1308 elements when not filtered

Comment: In principle you're right, but it's difficult to give a definitive answer without seeing how you `query` and  `predicate` are constructed. You can also check the generated search queries in the `Search.log` file - you can grab them and execute manually in the search engine to compare results.